# Informatica error : PCSF_46008 cannot connect to domain to lookup service

Tags: etl, admin, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I get this login error in Informatica Power center Designer frequently. I checked all the servers are running fine. Only i get this problem in my entire team. Any suggestions

Comment: Hi Sai, check the solution proposed in the following video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhO_twTnc6k

Comment: I think someone else also reported same issue few days back. Check your client connection to the repo server. You can use `ping -t infaserver` as well to check if connection between your machine and infa server is continuous or not.  Seems to me to be a network issue. If not, could you pls post ping results here.

Comment: @mohamed this issue seems to be unrelated to the video

Comment: @KoushikRoy - Th server is running and active. I did check with ping command. But i still have the same issue. Only I am facing this issue in my team.

Comment: can you ping the server from your client? how are you connecting to the infa server/network ? using vpn? or its in your local system? can you connect using putth simultaneously and see  if its dropping connection? Also can you pls check infa admin if they can see some connection drop from your user in rep log?

Comment: Yes. I am able to ping server from putty using VPN. Also there are no connection drop from user.